# How to I show update of my website on digitalOcean?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, web-hosting

I have a website that is hosted live, but whenever I update my source code and push it to git, the updates don't show. I found one poster who asked a similar question but the solution didn't work for me.

I launch the server with pm2 start index.js

I restarted it but still nothing.

Comment: See [the following](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-static-site-from-github-with-digitalocean-app-platform-quickstart#conclusion) from a tutorial post from DigitalOcean's site. It references deployment options.

Comment: @tomleb It's not a static side that I have, I have a server running on the backend.

Comment: Ok but did you read the "Conclusion" section? Are you sure it's not relevant in your case?

Comment: I created a droplet not an app, so it doesn't apply to me. I don't have an option to deploy.